# Clickable areas in SVG image that will lead to another image src

Tags: javascript, svg, clickable

Trying to create a point and click adventure game with SVG images and clickable path areas. For example, if you're in a hall way, and you click on a door, the img src will change to the next room corresponding with that door. I'm able to use addEventListener "click" and alert when the specific area is clicked. I just can't seem to get an idea on how to change the img src to the next room corresponding with that clicked area.

```
 //example img
<svg>
 <image xlink:href="/pointAndClickImg/Main Hall.svg"/>
 <path id="mainhall-left-door"/>
 <path id="mainhall-right-door/>
</svg>
```

```
 //example js that works with clicking and alerting
let mainHallLeftDoor = document.getElementById("leftdoor")
let mainHallRightDoor = document.getElementById("rightdoor")


mainHallLeftDoor.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("left door clicked")
    
})

mainHallRightDoor.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("right door clicked")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Image is a normal element and you can change all its attribute

```js
mainHallLeftDoor.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("left door clicked")
  const img = document.querySelector('svg image')
  img.setAttribute('xlink:href', '/pointAndClickImg/room.svg')

})
```

Comment: This works well but my only issue is when the picture swaps to the corresponding image with the click, it also carries over the path ways from the previous image.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use **one *delegated*** event listener

```html
<svg id=GAME viewBox="0 0 500 200" style="background:pink">
  <defs>
    <g id="room">
      <rect width="100" height="100" x="50" y="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"></rect>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use href="#room" fill="red" />
  <use href="#room" fill="yellow" x="150" />
  <use href="#room" fill="blue" x="300" />
</svg>
<script>
  // GAME.addEventListener( "click" , func );
  // or, for just one click:
  GAME.onclick = (evt) => {
    let clicked = evt.target;
    if (clicked.hasAttribute("fill")) {
      GAME.style.background = clicked.getAttribute("fill");
    }
  }
</script>
```